# Can I create an overlay layer to disable all touches, even on menus?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I need to show a popup layer on a scene, creating a semi-transparent background layer that will also prevent touch events propagation. I am using the latest cocos2d-x v. 3.0-alpha-0.

What I want to achieve is a popup layer that fully handles touches (eg. buttons, menu items, scroll views, etc.), laying on a background layer (for design purposes), that covers the current scene. All items in the scene should not respond to touches any more.

Is this achievable using the new `EventDispatcher` class? I've been able to disable all touches to the main scene, but all instances of `MenuItem` that live in the scene are still touchable and active.
How can I achieve this? And, also, how can I create a touch listener that prevents all touches to the main scene but not to the popup?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable menu items by setting setDisable property of menuitems to false.

Example

```
 _menuItem->setEnabled(false);
```

For Layers use setTouchEnabled property

```
 _backGroungLayer->setTouchEnabled(false);
```

Make sure that popup layer is not child of layer you want to disable.

To disable all items in menus do this

Suppose _menu contain various menuitems.

```
CCARRAY_FOREACH(_menu->getChildren(), item)
{
   item.isEnabled=NO; 
}
```

if you want to disable selected items just give them tags.There is no need to make any list.

Comment: All menu items live inside a table view. Isn't it possible to disable touches to menu items without having a full list of them? I would not like to save that list, since it's handled by a datasource, now.

Comment: I just added few lines for doing this.

Comment: If you disable CCSpriteMenuItems, you will change their appearance, which may not be what @marzapower wants to accomplish. I'm not certain about cocos2d-not-objectiveC, but with version 2.1 you should disable the Menus (not the menuitems). This prevents the menu's touch handler from accepting touches, thus propagating them to the embedded menu items. use the 'enabled' property of the menu, not the isTouchEnabled property of the underlying CCLayer.

Comment: `setTouchEnabled` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it with `mm`.  It was dirty, but it worked:

1. Create a button using `ccui.button`.
2. Set the button size to your screen size.
3. Add this button as a background to your popup layer.
4. This will prevent any thing behind it being clicked.

Answer (score 0):

By default, all CCMenu's have a set priority (kCCMenuHandlerPriority = -128) in cocos2d 2.1. So in a class (usually a CCNode descendant) that wants to swallow everything and preempt anything  i do like in this dialog sequencer example below :

```
- (void)onEnter {

    backdrop_.visible = self.isBackDropShown;
    MPLOG(@"Adding self as a swallower touch delegate, above the rest of the planet.");
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:_dialogTouchPriority swallowsTouches:YES];
    for (CCMenu *mn in _menus) {
       mn.touchPriotity = _dialogTouchPriority -1 ;
    }
    [super onEnter];
}
```

where _dialogTouchPriority is kCCMenuHandlerPriority-1 by default. It will be served before everything 'below'.  It is a bad hack (cocos2d internals could be changed and break this), i know , but bullet proof. Use carefully, make certain you only ever have one of these in your scene.

Comment: I'm not sure this will work in cocos2d-x 3.0. They've changed a bunch of things in event handling.

Comment: was not certain ... but it was just a thought. This alone could be reason enough for me to stop upgrading cocos2d and stay with 2.1 for as long as possible, if the same 'improvements' are brought to the objc code base. Work for work, i may chose to invest my time on SpriteKit.

Comment: It's not a complete redesign. Just a few things changed. You can still leverage the current knowledge of cocos2d if/when switching to 3.0.